# Change mail server settings in Outlook 2019

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

I try to change the mail server in an imap accoung of Outlook 2019. Fot that I select the account in account settings, click repair and select the advanced manual settings. Here I have the option to change the incoming and outgoing server. When I change this and click Next it says it was successful. But when I open it again I see nothing changed, there is still the old server.

Any ideas?